# How to redirect to a product page from a path such as mymagento.com/path?barcode=123

Tags: product, php, product-attribute, redirect, query

I know close to nothing about Magento, but need to add functionality to an existing Magento website, where when a user is taken to a path such as 'mymagento.com/path?barcode=123, it should redirect to the product with a custom attribute 'barcode' where the value is 123.

Where would the right place to add this path be?
Where would I place the php file that will be used for the above url?
How can I query the products, based on the 'barcode' attribute to find the correct redirect url?

Could someone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: Do you have any flexibility in changing the url `mymagento.com/path?barcode=123` to `mymagento.com/path/barcode/123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the admin, use Catalog > URL Rewrite Management to add new rewrite rules.

You can use advanced search to query the products:

> yoursite.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?barcode=185635242352.

Comment: Hi Phillip, thank you for your answer!
URL rewriting is not an option that I have, as the URLs should stay as they currently are.
Your advanced search suggestion is very close to what I wanted, I enabled the barcode attribute in Advanced Search, and when I pass in the barcode, I get taken to the 'products' page. Ideally, I'd like to be taken directly to the product itself, instead of the list.
Would you have any recommendations please?

Comment: Well, what I was thinking is, is using the rewrite to do that. Catalog Rewrite has a "Custom" option when adding new rewrites. So for example, you can make a catalog rewrite that would direct catalogsearch/advanced/result/?barcode=185635242352 to the product page for that barcode.

Comment: ah, I think I understand what you mean now Phillip, thanks!
Basically, I can redirect any url request, to any other url, is that correct? I was under the impression that Magento only allowed products and categories to be redirected. Thanks!
(I marked this as the accepted answer, but can't mark it as useful as well, as I don't have enough reputation :( )

Comment: Yes, if you choose custom, it allows you to redirect to any other URL. It can even be outside of Magento.